# Enum type within static class

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I ran into this legacy code that has static class that contains an enum and extension method with its own namespace. I have simplied it to below:

```
namespace AuxValidator
{

    public static class AuxValidator
    {

        public enum BadDataSentinal { UPPER = 0, LOWER = 1, WHATEVER = 2 }

        public static string Upper(this string field, BadDataSentinal badData, List<string> NewDataWatchlist = null)
        {
            if(badData == BadDataSentinal.UPPER)
               return field.Upper();

            return field
        }   
        

    }
}
```

This above class sits inside App_Code.

It is used in one of my **aspx.cs** file,

```
using AuxValidator;

public partial class SimplePage : RootPage
{
   private void updateBoxes(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args, string controlName, ValidationFunction f)
    {
        CustomValidator cv = (CustomValidator)source;
        TextBox src = ((TextBox)cv.FindControl(controlName));
        
        src.Text = args.Value.Upper(AuxValidator.AuxValidator.BadDataSentinal.UPPER);

    }
}
```

This works. However, notice in order to access the Enum, it has to first declare the namespace **AuxValidator**, then the class **AuxValidator** just to use the enum. If I take out the namespace and try to use it like `AuxValidator.BadDataSentinal.UPPER`, I will get:

> The type or namespace name 'BadDataSentinal' does not exist in the
> namespace 'AuxValidator'

It is a bit awkward, so intuitively, I take `BadDataSentinal` out of the class AuxValidator so I can access it simply with `BadDataSentinal.UPPER`.

Or,I can get rid of the namespace inside my `AuxValidator` class, so I can access like `AuxValidator.BadDataSentinal.UPPER`.

My question:

1: Why does a public enum inside static class needs to declare the namespace where it is used, despite already imported it with "using"

2: Is there any reason for public enum in static class?

Comment: this is probably necessary to resolve the abiguity between the Type and the Namespace

Comment: 1-When we define class within a namespace in C#, you need to specify the full name of the class to use it, even if you have imported the namespace with a using directive. This is because C# requires fully-qualified names to avoid naming conflicts between different namespaces. In your case, the BadDataSentinal enum is defined within the AuxValidator class, so you need to use the fully-qualified name AuxValidator.AuxValidator.BadDataSentinal to access it.
2-There may be a reason to define a public enum within a static class if the enum is closely related to functionality provided by the class.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one

Comment: There is another solution.  Change your `using` to `using static AuxValidator.AuxValidator`.  Then you will be able to use the enum simply as `BadDataSentinal.UPPER`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1: Why does a public enum inside static class needs to declare the
> namespace where it is used, despite already imported it with "using"

This is because the namespace and the class share the same name `AuxValidator` therefore the compiler will interpret AuxValidator as namespace. If they have different name you will not need to specifie the namespace twice

> 2: Is there any reason for public enum in static class?

Not really.

Answer (score 2):

All what you have is available to broad interpretation. But if you apply certain rules, you can standardize your code

*"Why does a public enum inside static class needs to declare the namespace where it is used, despite already imported it with "using""* - a good coding standards would make it illegal to have namespace and class to have same name. And here you have great example why this should be done - so you don't need to use full-qualifying name and for the code clarity.

*"Is there any reason for public enum in static class?"* - by good standards public enums can be declared in static or instance classes when such enums are used **only** by these classes and nowhere else.

*"Or,I can get rid of the namespace"* - you should rename the namespace to something different from your class. Besides, the classes and namespaces should have different naming styles. If your class is named in correct style - `AuxValidator`, the namespace should be something like `SomeValidation`. Since this is in `APP_Code`, you should have no issues renaming it because this is not something like redistribute library where you don't want to upset customers with breaking changes.